# Early Uncle Scrooge 1950's

Tags: story-identification, comics, scrooge-mcduck

Cover featured Uncle Scrooge diving to swimming pool fill with gold. I'm trying to buy one to fill in the childhood.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  All you know about this comic is the one cover image?

Comment: https://www.coverbrowser.com/covers/uncle-scrooge

Comment: https://d29xot63vimef3.cloudfront.net/image/uncle-scrooge/147-1.jpg has him tobaggoning.

Comment: Was it an *Uncle Scrooge* comic, a *Donald Duck* comic, or something in between. Some of the Uncle Scrooge reprints were from comics from other names.

Comment: ComicVine has a category listing for all [*Uncle Scrooge*](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/uncle-scrooge/4050-2103/?sortBy=asc) comics.  The earliest showing him swimming is #203, which wasn't published until 1983.  (The page includes links to the first 3 issues that were issued before it got its own line.)

Comment: I read Uncle Scrooge comics in the 1950s and am pretty certain he often dove and swam in money.  According to the tv tropes "pooled funds" trope, Scrooge should have been doing that as early as "Only a Poor Old Man", March 1952, since he tricks the Beagle Boys into trying it. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PooledFunds   --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_a_Poor_Old_Man